# XCode log output corrupted in LLDB

Tags: xcode, llvm, lldb

Since I switched to lldb, printing descriptions of many objects, especially UIViews, are corrupted. When it works, lldb is a great improvement, especially for things like dictionaries. However, I often get output such as the following. Is this a known issue, or could something be wrong in my configuration?

```
Printing description of v:
+ 6˝ú˝ Í|   HÜ0P«¡  `Owƒ˝Ä4Î    HÜ0†œ¡  86˝ú˝@ï0HÜ0\Ê˜`Owƒ˝@ï0HÜ0¯Â˜`6˝t˝@ï0HÜ0‰Ê˜`Owà˝@ï0HÜ0ÑÊ˜ú6˝$˝@ï0HÜ0ï∆   ∞6˝,˝@ï0HÜ00Ï˜`Ow8˝@ï0HÜ00ï∆    `Ow@˝@ï0HÜ0∞Î˜ÿ6˝ú˝x~|  HÜ0†π∆  `Owƒ˝†@—HÜ0¿π∆   retain:3 - tag:0 - bgcolor:(r:0 g:0 b:0 a:1.00)
   bounds: x:0 y:0 w:320 h:107 - frame: x:0 y:0 w:320 h:107 - center: x:160, y:54
++ \˝ú˝H≥|  HÜ0¿ô„  `Owƒ˝ÔË    HÜ0PSÁ  0\˝ú˝Pz«    HÜ0†t«  `Owƒ˝ù«    HÜ0Ät«  X\˝ú˝xø|    HÜ0@’∆  `Owƒ˝„∆    HÜ0`’∆  `Ow–\˝@ï0HÜ0`@∆ l\˝º\˝@ï0HÜ0@@∆ ®\˝LOw‡/Ñ   HÜ0Ä{«  `Ow`OwPÈ∆   HÜ0@û«  –\˝ú˝0Ñ    HÜ0∞7∆  `Owƒ˝‡È∆    HÜ0–7∆  ¯\˝LOwê-Ñ   HÜ0–/»  `Ow`Owê!»   HÜ0PC»  p]˝LOw@ï0HÜ0¿>˙`Ow‹PH@ï0HÜ0–9˙ ]˝»PH@ï0HÜ0‹;˙\]˝LOw–n°HÜ00C»    `Ow`OwàêHÜ0pR»  `Ow`Ow@ï0HÜ0‡=˙ò]˝$˝∞Ì« HÜ0`»   `Ow8˝‡Ï∆    HÜ0@    »   ¿]˝º\˝@ï0HÜ0‡e∆ `Ow–\˝@ï0HÜ0f∆  Ë]˝º\˝b|    HÜ0 V∆  `Ow–\˝∞ÍÉ   HÜ0PV∆  ^˝ÃL˝àÇ|    HÜ0Pπ±  `Ow‡L˝†TÉHÜ0@±  8^˝ÃL˝@ï0HÜ0xD˙`Ow‡L˝@ï0HÜ0pC˙`^˝úO˝@Ú| HÜ0pw±  `Ow∞O˝`N±   HÜ0†P±  à^˝M˝@ï0HÜ0∞G˙`Ow0M˝@ï0HÜ0»F˙∞^˝¸Ä˝ h|  HÜ0¿∆   `OwÅ˝¿˚–HÜ0ê∆   ÿ^˝ÃL˝ ÑÎ   HÜ00WÎ  `Ow‡L˝¿UÎ   HÜ0WÎ    retain:4 - tag:0 - bgcolor:(r:0 g:0 b:0 a:1.00)
    bounds: x:0 y:0 w:320 h:107 - frame: x:0 y:0 w:320 h:107 - center: x:160, y:54
+++ ,å= retain:4 - tag:11 - bgcolor:(r:30 g:198 b:32 a:1.00)
     bounds: x:0 y:0 w:420 h:403 - frame: x:-50 y:9 w:420 h:403 - center: x:160, y:210
++++ Tå= retain:4 - tag:0 - bgcolor:(r:0 g:0 b:0 a:1.00)
      bounds: x:0 y:0 w:403 h:403 - frame: x:0 y:0 w:403 h:403 - center: x:202, y:202
```

Comment: What other logging do you do before it gets corrupted? maybe you output some raw strings that gets interpreted as control codes?

Comment: But hmm is it only the class names that gets corrupted somehow? are you sure it started to happen when you switched to lldb and not after some Xcode upgrade? does it only happen when you dump view trees (which is some non-apple addition i guess)?

Comment: No control codes are sent--this occurs even when it's the first output. It seems to be only UIView subclasses where this occurs--custom objects don't exhibit this. If I switch back to GDB there is no corruption.